# Proving the geometric sum formula by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction, geometric-progressions

$$\sum_{k=0}^nq^k = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

I want to prove this by induction. Here's what I have.

$$\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} + q^{n+1} = \frac{1-q^{n+1}+q^{n+1}(1-q)}{1-q}$$

I wanted to factor a $q^{n+1}$ out of the second expression but that 1- is screwing it up...

Comment: It's fully correct... just expand the term in the parenthesis and cancel out the two terms in the middle...

Comment: Multiply through. You get on top $1-q^{n+1}+q^{n+1}-q^{n+2}$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. I'm no good at this sort of thing.

Comment: also: what happens if q= 1 in this sum? obviously the zero denominator causes a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1 - q^{n+1} + q^{n+1}(1-q) = 1 - q^{n+1}(1 - (1-q)) = 1 - (q^{n+1} \cdot q) = \cdots $$

Answer (score 2):

Did you try expanding the numerator? You have $1-q^{n+1}+q^{n+1}-q^{n+2}$..

Comment: Can you please help me with this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177377/forall-x-in-mathbbz-x-neq-1-implies-left-forall-n-in-mathbbn?noredirect=1#comment4478886_2177377

Comment: I don't know how to factor it ending up with $\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$.