# Induction Proof with a $\neq$ 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

For $a \neq 1$ and $n>0$, $(1-a^{n+1})/(1-a)=1+a+a^2+...+a^n$

How do you prove this by induction?

Comment: have u done any induction proof before

Comment: It's a bit goofy to prove this by induction, when you can just prove it by polynomial multiplication!

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/658992/23353 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29023/23353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $P(n): \dfrac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} = 1+a+a^2+...+a^n$ is true . We show $P(n+1)$ is true, i.e.

We have: $\dfrac{1-a^{n+2}}{1-a} = \dfrac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} + a^{n+1} = (1+a+...a^n) + a^{n+1}$, by the induction step.

We're done.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, $LHS=1+a=RHS$

Assume this is true for $n=p\geq 1$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{1-a^{p+1}}{1-a}=1+a+a^2+...+a^p$. Now add $a^{p+1}$ to both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The statement holds for $n=1$.

We can rewrite the statement for $n$ as

$$1 - a^{n+1} = (1-a)(1+a+a^2+...+a^n).$$

Assuming this to be true, the case for $n+1$ is

$$1 - a^{n+2} = (1-a)(1+a+a^2+...+a^n + a^{n+1}) \\ = (1-a)(1+a+a^2+...+a^n) + (1-a)a^{n+1} \\ = [1 - a^{n+1}] + a^{n+1} - a^{n+2} = 1-a^{n+2},$$

and we've won.

(The bracketed term on the last line made use of the inductive assumption.)

Answer (score 1):

let $P(n)$ represent the statement that ($a \ne 1$)
$$
\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} = \sum_{k=0}^n a^k
$$
then $P(0)$ is easily seen to be true. suppose the statement $P(n)$ were true. then adding $a^{n+1}$ to both sides we have
$$
\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} +a^{n+1}= \sum_{k=0}^n a^k + a^{n+1}
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{1-a^{n+1} +a^{n+1}(1-a)}{1-a} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a^k 
$$
the LHS simplifies to $\frac{1-a^{n+2}}{1-a} $, so we have shown that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$ which is the required inductive step to bootstrap the result through all the positive integers

Comment: Here it says $n>0$

Comment: well you may consider the truth of the statement for $n=0$ as a bonus

Comment: @DavidHolden It does hold for $n=0$, correct.  But does this answer the question as asked?  You didn't actually verify that the equation held for one of the valid values.  This may be a technicality but ... maybe there's an edge case somewhere where doing something like this would get you in trouble?