# Why is this true $\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=(1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-1})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

I have a heard time seeing why is this true
$\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=(1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-1})$

Could you show me some kind of proof, or an identity that would me to find this?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying through by the denominator?

Comment: You can try polynomial division and notice a pattern. The most natural way to see it, IMO, is through induction because it's clearly true for $n=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: A word you may want to learn is **telescoping sum** it means that in a sum each term and the next cancel. That is what happens for this sum if you multiply each side with $1-y$.

Comment: Covered by answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023), listed in Meta's [List of generalizations of common questions](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868).

Comment: Also answered by [Proving the geometric sum formula by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic result for the sum $S_{n-1}$ of a geometric progression :

Let $$S_{n-1} = \sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-1}y^k=1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-2}+ y^{n-1}$$

Thus, you have : 
\begin{align}
y\times S_{n-1}&=y+y^2+y^3+...+y^{n-1}+ y^{n}\\
& \Rightarrow S_{n-1}-yS_{n-1} =1-y^n\\
& \Rightarrow S_{n-1}(1-y)=1-y^n\\
& \Rightarrow S_{n-1} = \frac{1-y^n}{1-y}\\
\end{align}
$\square$

Answer (score 6):

$(1-y)(1+y+y^2+\ldots+y^{n-1})=1+ \not\!y+\not\!y^2+\ldots+\not\!y^{n-1}-\not\!y-\not\!y^2-\ldots-\not\!y^{n-1}-y^n=$ $$1-y^n$$

Answer (score 3):

You can check pretty easily that $1-y^n = (1-y)(1 + y + y^2 + \cdots  y^{n-1})$.  Notice that, in distributing, you get a positive copy of every monomial in $1 + y + \cdots + y^{n-1}$, and a negative copy of a ton of powers of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}
&=\frac{1\color{red}{-y+y}\color{blue}{-y^2+y^2}-y^3+\cdots+y^{n-2}\color{magenta}{-y^{n-1}+y^{n-1}}-y^n}{1-y}\\
&=\frac{(1\color{red}{-y})+y(\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{-y})+y^2(\color{blue}{1}-y)+\cdots+y^{n-2}(1\color{magenta}{-y})+y^{n-1}(\color{magenta}{1}-y)}{1-y}\\
&=\frac{(1-y)(1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{n-2}+y^{n-1})}{1-y}\\
&=1+y+y^2+\cdots+y^{n-2}+y^{n-1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can proceed by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, we have
$$\frac{1-y}{1-y}=1=\sum_{k=0}^0 y^k.$$
Now suppose that 
$$\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-1}$$
For some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then we have
$$ 1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-1}+y^n= \frac{1-y^n}{1-y}+y^n=\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}+\frac{y^n(1-y)}{1-y}=\frac{1-y^{n+1}}{1-y}.$$
Therefore, the formula is valid for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a proof, more of a motivator to give you the intuition that the formula *should* work: calculate a few examples with $y=10$ and smallish $n$, after multiplying numerator and denominator by $-1$ to get

$$\frac{y^n-1}{y-1}$$

Example with $n=5$:

$$\frac{10^5-1}{10-1} = \frac{99999}{9} = 11111 = 10^4+10^3+10^2+10^1+10^0$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if

$$
s_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k = as + ar + ar^2 + \dots + ar^{n-1}, 
$$

then

$$
s_n(1 - r) = s_n - rs_n  = a - ar^n = a(1-r^n),
$$

so

$$
s_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}.
$$