# Proving $ \sum^{m}_{i=0} N^{i} = \frac{N^{m+1}-1}{N-1} $

Tags: summation, notation

I found this equation in a computer science article:
$$ \sum^{m}_{i=0} N^{i} = \frac{N^{m+1}-1}{N-1} $$
and I'm really unsure why this is true. I tried to come up with an answer myself, I arbitrarily chose $m$ to be equal to 4, here are my equations:
$$ \sum^{4}_{i=0} N^{i} = 1 + N + N^{2} + N^{3} + N^{4} = N(N^{3} + N^{2} + N + 1) + 1 $$
After this I'm not sure where to go, somehow I should be able to reach $N^{5}$ (as in $\frac{N^{5}-1}{N-1}$) but I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: $$(1-N)(1+N+N^2+...+N^m)=1+N+N^2+...+N^m-N-N^2-...-N^{m+1}=1-N^{m+1}.$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this true $\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}=(1+y+y^2+...+ y^{n-1})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867880/why-is-this-true-frac1-yn1-y-1yy2-yn-1)

Comment: Is it true when $m=0$? What is added to each side when you increase $m$ from $k$ to $k+1$? Now you can prove it by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\color{red}{S_m} = \sum_{i = 0}^m {N^i} = \color{blue}{1} + \color{red}{N + N^2 +..... N^{m}}$$
$$\color{green}{N\times S_m} =N\times \sum_{i = 0}^m {N^i} = \sum_{i = 0}^m N^{i+1} = \color{red}{N + N^2 + N^3 +...N^{m}}+ \color{blue}{N^{m+1}} $$
Subtraction $S_m \text{ from }N\times S_m$ which will cancel out the red colored terms and only blue colored terms will left

On the left side we have, $N\times S_m -S_m = S_m(N-1)$  while on the right side we'll have $(N^{m+1}-1)$

Thus,
$$\color{blue}{N\times S_m}-\color{blue}{S_m} = \color{brown}{S_m}\times \color{green}{(N-1)} = \color{green}{N^{m+1} - 1} \text{ dividing both sides with }(N-1)\\\implies  \color{brown}{S_m} = \frac {N^{m+1}-1}{N-1}$$

For the above solution, we can divide with $(N-1)$ only when $N\ne1$ but we still can use the above formula as $\lim_{N\to1}$ and apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: I almost understand your solution, I only have two further questions, why does this equation apply: $S m \times (N - 1) = N^{m+1} - 1$ ? I understand that $Sm \times N$ is equal to $N^{m+1}$, but why is $Sm \times (-1)$ equal to $(-1)$? 

My other question is why does $N \times Sm - Sm = N^{m+1} - 1$ imply $S = \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$? I don't see the connection there, I'm kind of inexperienced in this field of maths.

Comment: @Patyo21 I have added further explanation hope this will help you.

Comment: The further explanation made everything clear to me, now I understand it completely. Thank you very much, I have marked your solution as accepted.

Comment: Why don't you mention the term "finite sum of a geometric series" ? Besides computation and proof, terminology is also an important part of the knowledge we have to convey to a student.

Answer (score 0):

Start by:
$$
S(m) = \sum_{k=0}^m N^k = 1+N+N^2+...+N^m \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Now multiply equation $\eqref{1}$ by $N$, which gives us:
$$
NS(m) = N + N^2 + N^3 +... + N^m + N^{m+1}\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Now $\eqref{2} - \eqref{1}$ is equal to:
$$
S(m) - NS(m) = 1 + (N-N) + (N^2-N^2) +... + (N^m - N^m) -N^{m+1} = 1-N^{m+1}\Rightarrow S(m)(1-N) = 1-N^{m+1}
$$
Now if $N\ne 1\implies \boxed{S(m) = \frac{1-N^{m+1}}{1-N}}$

If $N = 1\implies \boxed{S(m)= m + 1}$, this is because $s(m)=\sum_{k=0}^m 1 = \underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1}_{m + 1 \text{ times}}$