# $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z^+}, x \neq 1 \implies \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right) $

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Can someone please prove this?

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z^+}, x \neq 1 \implies \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right) $$

I'm confused over whether to add $x^k$ or $x^{k+1}$ to the right hand side and have gotten nowhere in both cases. Just can't factor it out like the rest of them. It would be much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Note: This is cleary a different one from [Proving the geometric sum formula by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction) so please stop down-voting.

Comment: This the classical sum of a limited geometrical series: you find it in all textbooks and web resources e;g.,(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html). Usually it is presented for any real $x$ different from $1$. It is true a fortiori if you restrict $x$ to be a positive integer...

Comment: $x$ doesn't have to lie in $\mathbf Z^+$  for this formula to hold. To prove it, just start from the high-school formula $a^n-b^n=\dotsm$.

Comment: What do you want more than a site where what you ask is proven (and even in the more general context of reals : do you agree that integers are included into reals ?).

Comment: I am simply asking how to proceed from $ \frac{x^k -1 + x^{k+1}(x-1)}{x-1} $ as I cannot seem to end up with $\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$. Please stop over-complicating everything and refrain from commenting or down-voting when you choose not to be helpful or constructive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the geometric sum formula by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction)

Comment: So... you are asking why $$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ right? But this is what is done on the page you mention (approx. 2.5 times), no?

Comment: @Did No, allow me to demonstrate in my own answer.

Comment: I fail to imagine how your "own answer" to come will show that the linked page does not fully answer your question...

Comment: And now we can see that, unsurprisingly, your "own answer" closely mimicks some answers on the page this one duplicates. Useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
   \text{We want to prove:} \ \forall x \in \mathbb{Z^+}, x \neq 1 \implies \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)
  \end{align*}
            Let $x \in \mathbb{R^+}$. Assume that $x\neq1$.

Let $P(n)$ be the claim: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$
            For the **base case, $n=0$**:

The $L.H.S.=\sum_{i=0}^{0-1}{x^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{-1}{x^i}=0$.

The $R.H.S.=\frac{x^0-1}{x-1}=\frac{1-1}{x-1}=0$

Therefore, $P(0)$ holds.

Assuming **$P(k)$** holds for $n=k$, we have:
            \begin{align*}
    P(k):\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{x^i}=\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}
   \end{align*}
            We need to prove **$P(k+1)$** which should be:
            $$\sum_{i=0}^{k}{x^i}=\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1} $$
            Now, we know \begin{align*}
       \sum_{i=0}^{k}{x^i} &= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{x^i} +x^k\\
       &= \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}+x^k\\
       &= \frac{x^k-1+x^k(x-1)}{x-1}\\
       &= \frac{x^k-1+x^k.x-x^k)}{x-1}\\
       &= \frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}\\
      \end{align*}
            And so $P(k+1)$ holds.