# How does a simplification like this work?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, induction

This is an example of mathematical induction from my textbook.

What I want to know is how the equation gets simplified to that. It's probably something simple but I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a(1+r^k)}{(1-r)} + ar^k
&= \frac{a}{1-r}\cdot(1-r^k+r^k-r^{k-1})
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you dealing with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a(1+r^k)}{1-r}+ar^k=\frac{a(1+r^k)+ar^k(1-r)}{1-r}=\frac{a}{1-r}(1+r^k+r^k-r^{k+1})$$

Maybe you mean the following?
$$\frac{a(1-r^k)}{1-r}+ar^k=\frac{a(1-r^k)+ar^k(1-r)}{1-r}=\frac{a}{1-r}(1-r^k+r^k-r^{k+1})$$

Comment: Aw man thank you so much I totally forgotten about multiplying with the denominator.