# Show that : $1 + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n}) + ...... + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n})^{n-1} = \frac{n}{x}(1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n}) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

How can I prove that : $\,\forall\,n \ge1 \, ,x>0 $

> $$1 + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n}) + ...... + ( 1 - \frac{x}{n})^{n-1} = \frac{n}{x}(1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n})
> \;\;\;\:\:\:$$

thanks in advance .

Comment: Hello , yes it does thanks ,all the answers below are also good .

Answer (score 2):

you try to calculate 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{p}^k$$ with $p=1-\frac{x}{n}$
We know that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{p}^k=\frac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}$$

Therefore,
 $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{p}^k=\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}}{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})}=\frac{n}{x}(1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n})$$

Answer (score 2):

It is a geometric series
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X^i = \frac{1-X^n}{1-X}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $X=(1-x/n)$ and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
1 + \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n} \right) + ...... + \left( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}  = \frac{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^n}{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})} \\
= \frac{n}{x} \left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

In general, the following formula is true ([which you can confirm through mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction)):$\sum_{i=0}^k X^i=\frac{1-X^{k+1}}{1-X}.$

Substituting $X=1-\frac xn$ and $k=n-1,$ we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
1+(1-\frac xn)+\cdots+(1-\frac xn)^{n-1}&=\frac{1-(1-\frac xn)^n}{1-(1-\frac xn)}\\
&=\frac nx\left(1-{\left(1-\frac xn\right)}^n\right).\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

From the high school formula:
\begin{align}
&&1-u^n&=(1-u)(1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1})\\[1ex]
&\text{whence }\qquad& 1+u+u^2+\dots+u^{n-1}&=\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}.
\end{align}
Now set $\;u=1-\dfrac xn$ to obtain
$$1 + \Bigl( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\Bigr) + … + \Bigl( 1 - \frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n-1}=\frac{1-\Bigl(1-\cfrac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n}}{\not1-\Bigl(\not1-\cfrac xn\Bigr)}=\frac nx\biggl(1-\Bigl(1-\cfrac{x}{n}\Bigr)^{n}\biggr).$$